# Run Airflow webserver behind a AWS ELB with HTTPS and page forward to http after click trigger a DAG

Tags: https, webserver, airflow, gunicorn, amazon-elb

I am running airflow(version 1.10.10) webserver on EC2 behind AWS ELB

Here is the ELB listener configuration

```
Load Balancer Protocol : SSL Load Balancer 
Port:      443 Instance
Protocol:       TCP Instance 
Port:           8080 
Cipher          omit here 
SSL Certificate          a cert here
```

in front of ELB , i configured a route53 and set a fqdn to the web server say: abc.fqdn

all the page loading are working, like
https://abc.fqdn/admin/ or
https://abc.fqdn/admin/airflow/tree?dag_id=tutorial

all the web form submission are working , like
Trigger DAG

however, after form submission, the page is forwarded to an http and the page did not load due to the elb listener.
I have to manually change to https such as  https://admin/airflow/tree?dag_id=tutorial

here is what i did:
I read about this article: https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/issues/978

then on the webserver ec2 , i found this file /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/gunicorn_config.py

and this example config : https://gist.github.com/kodekracker/6bc6a3a35dcfbc36e2b7

i added the following config and my config file looks like below

```
import setproctitle
from airflow import settings

secure_scheme_headers = {
    'X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL': 'ssl',
    'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https',
    'X-FORWARDED-SSL': 'on'
}

forwarded_allow_ips = "*"

proxy_protocol = True

proxy_allow_from = "*"

def post_worker_init(dummy_worker):
    setproctitle.setproctitle(
        settings.GUNICORN_WORKER_READY_PREFIX + setproctitle.getproctitle()
    )
```

However, the new configs above seems not working.
Did I do anything wrong? How to make may web node forward to https after form submission?

Answer (score 0):

For https I used an ALB instead… Had to setup the Airflow web server to have a crt (generated self signed with the domain that will be used by the ALB) then serving on port 8443 (choose anything you like), then set the ALB to route https to the target group the webserver ASG instances are in for 8443; and you tell the ALB to use the signed cert that you already have (not the self signed that's on the instance) in your AWS account (probably).

Oh and change the baseURL to https schema.

I had trouble with the ELB because I was directing similarly 443 with cert in AWS account to 8080, but 8080 was unencrypted…